# I don't want Flash, how do I make IE stop asking about installing it?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, browser-addons, internet-explorer-9, flash-player

I don't have Flash installed, so on many web pages I get a dialogue which says something like "this website wants to install the following add-on: Adobe Flash Player".

Can I set this dialogue to never appear? I don't want Flash but I don't want to have to tell that to IE every single time. Can I make it remember that I don't want it?

Comment: I do not think you can get rid of it since usually that is coded into the webpage you are going to.

Comment: I pretty sure that it's a standard IE dialog.

Comment: I don't think there is a way in IE to block flash but  I know in Chrome and Firefox they have plugins for it. One option would be to disable Shockwave flash object add on on IE. Tools>Manage Add ons

Answer (score 1):

You can disable this prompt, but that will cause *all* add-ons to be disabled.

1. Open Group Policy Editor: Press [Windows] + [R], enter `gpedit.msc` and click *OK*.
2. On the left, navigate to *Computer Configuration, Administrative Templates, Windows Components, Internet Explorer, Internet Control Panel, Advanced features*.
3. On the right, double-click on *Allow third-party browser extensions*.
4. Select *Disabled*, and confirm with *OK*.
5. Restart Internet Explorer and try to visit the page that was previously prompting you to install Flash Player.

Comment: Did not work on IE11 / Win7; the prompt still appears.